# How does "задирать" differ from "доставать"?

Tags: выбор-слова

> Она меня постоянно **задирает**.
>
> Она меня постоянно **достает**.

In conversation, I use "задирать" or "доставать" with the meaning of "сильно раздражать". I'm wondering how they compare with one another in terms of nuance, usage, and register?

Comment: Dictionaries are extremely helpful. I would try finding one you like. There's also Reverso. Almost all the questions you ask could be answered in a few seconds.

доставать—разг. (приставать к кому-л, раздражать кого-л) get (at); pester (d); annoy (d); get smb's goat sl

задирать— (кого-л.; дразнить)
pick (on), bully (d.)

Comment: @VCH250 You seem to be quite fond of dictionaries, I see, but language learning isn't as simple as that -- going through dictionaries and voilà your knowing everything just like that. Sure, if you are content with a superficial understanding, definitions in dictionaries will suffice. However, if you hope to reach the level of native speakers, hardly so. Haven't I already mentioned this before, but the answers given by native speakers here are hardly what you can find in dictionaries. And as for Reverso, I don't recommend relying on it too much  outside of getting a broad understanding.

Comment: @VCH250 Just to illustrate the point, the definition "**приставать к кому-л**" that you listed for "доставать" also holds true for "задирать". Which goes to show that the distinction isn't as clear-cut as you make it out to be, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5):

> In conversation, I use "задирать" or "доставать" with the meaning of
>   "сильно раздражать". I'm wondering how they compare with one another
>   in terms of nuance, usage, and register?

With this meaning, there is a difference between these verbs in the imperfective form: "Задирать" is to provoke a conflict, a physical fight, or a verbal fight, while ''доставать'' is merely to annoy with persistent action, to get to, often with a purpose of making the victim change his course of actions.

A classical situation of ''задирать'': One schoolboy bullies another one and challenges him to a fist fight, simply willing to test the fists and get some adrenaline. A classical situation of ''доставать'': A wife constantly reminds her husband that he earns not enough money, trying to make him change his job for a better one.

A persistent mosquito or a fly can доставать, but cannot задирать.

Задиристый person is someone aggressive, verbally or physically. Доставучий person is just someone persistent in his annoying actions.

In the perfective form, however, these verbs are equivalent: ''Задрал уже'' = ''Достал уже'' = ''You have got to me.'' However, ''задрал'' is used rarely as compared to ''достал''.

Comment: seeing **задрал** it's occurred to me that it might be derived from **задирать** which in the past seem to have never been used in perfective aspect, i've usually attributed it to euphemistic **заебать**

Answer (score 2):

**доставать** is either **`to bug with smth, to rag on`**, incessant requests, questions or addresses, if done on purpose, or **`to annoy`** if causing nuisance unintentionally and unwittingly, a synonym of **действовать на нервы**, this verb can accept complement in Instrumental, that is **доставать чем-то** or **с чем-то** which is rarer

**задирать** is **`to tease, to banter`** as already said, but also **`to try to pick a fight, to badger, to yank one's chain`** if done with malicious intent, whose synonym is **задираться к** typical to children vocabulary in the past, don't think it's still common, this one is used without complement to denote means whereby the act is done

**задирать** is perceived as significantly older, **доставать** is pretty recent, i've started hearing it a lot since end of the 80s beginning of the 90s

the adverb **постоянно** signals that act or its effect are deliberate

Comment: So is the sense of **annoyance** not necessarily an integral part of the meaning of these verbs?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens only that of **доставать** in specific usages

Comment: I thought "достать" could also have the meaning of "piss off" or "drive crazy". I have the famous video game "Neighbors from Hell" in mind here which in Russian is trandlated as "как достать соседа." This title might be translated as "How to drive your neighbor crazy"

Comment: @студент001 rather **drive crazy**  than **piss off**

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same only in the forms **задрал** and **достал**, that is perfective past. Both are colloquial, and достал is softer, if it is possible to be softer here.

In the present form **задирает** or any other imperfective forms this verb means **teasing**.

**Достаёт** in its indirect meaning is "сильно раздражает, старается вывести из себя". Literally it is 'keeps trying to get you out of yourself'.

Answer (score 1):

Задирать - trying to provoke aggressive response.
Доставать - to annoy